# close the DIV when clicked outside it, even when clicked on the scrollbars of any parent DIVs

Tags: javascript

My goal with this example is for the blue bloxes `.box` to close whenever you click outside of them, even if you click on the scrollbars.

My problem, and **my question**, is that this example works, but not in my full project, once in my full project I have to call/include the `<script src="">` inside the `<head>` before the entire `<html>` page is loaded. What other alternatives do I have, perhaps using `addeventlistener` for the `scroll` of each `<div>`, without being forced to call the `<script>` at the end of each page?

**note:** Keep in mind that in my full project, I use the classes of each `<div>` instead of using IDs.

```js
function closeBoxes() {

  if(event.target.closest(".box") === null){
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    boxes.forEach(e =>{ e.style.display = "none"; });
  }

}

let alldiv = document.querySelectorAll("div");
alldiv.forEach(e =>{ e.onscroll = (event) => { closeBoxes(); }; });

window.addEventListener("click", function(){ closeBoxes(); });
```

```css
.main { 
  background-color: #e6e6e6; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px; 
  height: 170px; 
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container { 
  background-color: #ffccff; 
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 220px; 
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child { 
  background-color: #ffffcc; 
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 270px; 
  padding: 10px;
}

.box { 
  background-color: #ccd8ff; 
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  click outside the blue boxes to close them
    <div class="container">
      <div class="child">
        <div class="box">BOX-A1<br>BOX-A2<br>BOX-A3<br>BOX-A4<br>BOX-A5</div>
        <div class="box">BOX-B1<br>BOX-B2<br>BOX-B3<br>BOX-B4<br>BOX-B5</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `let alldiv = document.querySelectorAll("div");` won't find anything, if you embed this script _before_ those `div` elements. If you still want to be able to embed your script in the head - then use _event delegation_ for this part.

Comment: Is it possible, that you've more than one `.child` element with boxes?

Comment: @CBroe - I have the perception of this. That's why I already warned you in the question. Do you have an alternative to teach me?

Comment: Yes, and I already mentioned it. So that is the point at which you should _research_ the keyword you have been given, if you are not familiar with it yet.

Comment: @CBroe - i've tried the *event delegation* as `[...document.getElementsByTagName("div")].forEach(e =>{ e.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => { closeBoxes(); }) });` but still with the same problem, i call `<script>` on `<head>` when no `<div>` were initianted.

Comment: How is that event delegation? You are still trying to add an event handler to every individual div there - which might not even exist at this point, hence your problem. Event delegation would mean that you handle this at an "upper level", on an ancestor of these elements that will _always_ exist.

Comment: @CBroe - can you please give me an example with my posted code? If you know a better solution, you could help me and the comunity as well. TY

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/1427878 - the top answer there has a good explanation, plus links to further examples.

Comment: @CBroe - dear, `window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ closeBoxes(); }, true)` simple as this, with a `useCapture` parameter = true ; works very well with my function `closeBoxes();`.

Answer (score 0):

The script tag had an attribute called defer. This will allow us to place the script on the head without having an issue. For your reference.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: sorry, the `<script defer>` doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: Is your javascript code in an external files ?

Comment: yes, `<head><script src="../../some_folder/script.js" defer></script></head>`, error:  "Uncaught Reference Error: XYZ is not defined at php_script.php:139:3" ; XYZ it's a literal object inside the `script.js` file .

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add an `window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){},true);` with `useCapture` parameter = true;

```
function closeBoxes() {

  if(event.target.closest){ console.log("entrou"); }

  // EDITED - `event.target.closest` can't be false, prevents >> TypeError: evt.target.closest is not a function
  if(event.target.closest && event.target.closest(".box") === null){
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    boxes.forEach(e =>{ e.style.display = "none"; });
  }

}

window.addEventListener("click", function(){ closeBoxes(); });

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ closeBoxes(); }, true); // NEW - with `useCapture` parameter = true;
```

*"With the addEventListener() method you can specify the propagation type by using the "useCapture" parameter: `addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);`

The default value is false, which will use the bubbling propagation, **when the value is set to true, the event uses the capturing propagation.**"*

**font:** https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp